# JavaScript get elements by class name and tag name

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to get a list of DOM elements by class name and tag name in JavaScript, not using jQuery.

For example I need to get all `<ul>` elements with class `.active`

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var activeElements = document.getElementsByClassName('active')
```

What is the fastest and best way to do this in JavaScript.

No external libraries like jQuery or [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

Comment: To be pedantic, in *pure* JavaScript there's no way to do it, because *pure* JavaScript doesn't have anything to do with a DOM.  But what you're looking for is `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: [Locating DOM elements using selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul.active')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it, [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of the elements within the document that match the specified group of selectors. Supported in IE8+