# If URL contains this string then hide all divs with this class/id (loop script)

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, getelementbyid, selectors-api

I am trying to hide some divs when url contains an specific string.

For example, i have this code that hides the first div:

```
   <div id="ficha">Hello</div>
   <div id="ficha">world</div>
   <div id="ficha">...</div>

   <script>
      if (/info|mapo/.test(window.location.href)) {
        document.getElementById('ficha').style.display = 'none';
        }
   </script>
```

URLs:

www.example.com/all  ------> Not hide the div

www.example.com/info-----> Hide the div

www.example.com/mapo---> Hide the div

1. The first problem with the script is that it only hides the first div saying Hello, but i want to hide all the divs. So, i think it's necessary to do a loop... ¿how can i do that?
2. The second thing is running two different scripts to hide different divs according the url string content.

Maybe this can be achived by making an else function. Always the loop its necessary and even better if it's executed after load page.

For example:

```
   <div id="ficha">Hello</div>
   <div id="ficha">Hello2</div>
   <div id="ficha2">world</div>
   <div id="ficha2">...</div>

   <!-- First script hides divs with id="ficha" if url string has "info" or "mapo" -->
   <script>
      if (/info|mapo/.test(window.location.href)) {
        document.getElementById('ficha').style.display = 'none';
        }
   </script>

   <!-- Second script hides divs with id="ficha2" if url string has "all" -->
   <script>
      if (/all/.test(window.location.href)) {
        document.getElementById('ficha2').style.display = 'none';
        }
   </script>
```

The code will be execute in Database Activity of Moodle.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have more than one element with any given ID, as ID's are unique.

Comment: try using classes instead of ids `<div class="ficha">` and then use `document.getElementsByClassName` to iterate over all selected elements. An ID must be assigned to only one element.

Answer (score 0):

This script will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () { //The function to execute when the page is loaded
    var string_contain = ''; //Set this as your string
    var url = window.location.href;
    if(url.indexOf(string_contain) >= 0) { //If url contains then...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("your_class"); //Create an array that contains your divs with your_class class
        for(var a = 0;a<x.length;a++) { //Do some stuff for each value of the array
            x[a].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="your_class"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Remeber that the ID is associated with just one element, so it won't work if you're trying to access more than one element.

Comment: @Gonzalo If you liked my solution, I invite you to give a positive vote to my answer or set it to your answer, to help me to be active on StackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: I think i cannot: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues here:

First, like user adeneo mentioned in their comment, you cannot share IDs.  Classes, however, can be shared so you probably want your `<div>` elements to say `class="ficha"`.

Second, you want to hide or show divs based off of a string in the URL, but your URLs are composed of unique paths.  You're trying to hide divs, when you should just be building the pages differently.  Unless there's more information you need to add about this.

`www.example.com/mapo` is, at least in the representation you've provided, a different HTML page from `www.example.com/info` so why not build them as separate pages rather than going through unnecessary logic to show and hide `<div>` elements?

The third issue: you don't want a for loop so much as a for-each loop.  This first question will give you direction on how to select all elements with the specified class:
[JavaScript get elements by class name and tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194140/javascript-get-elements-by-class-name-and-tag-name)
Then using the array you've selected from the above information, you can use [Javascript Documentation for using forEach on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to change your elements' visibility.

Comment: thanks for the list of issues. I wanted to keep it simple, buy may be is confusing.
1. You cannot share IDs (a basic error of myself)
2. String URLs are search filters like this one "mod/data/view.php?d=4&perpage=10&search=&sort=0&order=ASC&advanced=0&filter=1&advanced=1&f_32=mapo&f_23=&f_24=&f_26=&f_27=&f_28=&f_30="
3. Thats what i have to learn.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Since its not unique, a CSS class would be more appropriate. Something like this should work:

```
    function hideItemsByClass(className){
        var matchedItems = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
        for(var i = 0; i < matchedItems.length; i++){
            matchedItems[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```